# WinJS Crossfade between background images

Tags: javascript, css, windows-store-apps, winjs

I have a WinJS Windows 8 store app.  The background of my app displays an image:

```
body {    
   background-image: url('/images/myimage.jpg');
   background-size: cover;
}
```

What I want to happen is to cross-fade this image on a button click.  I tried extracting the above into a separate css class, and then referencing this in the JS:

```
function myButtonClick() {
    WinJS.UI.Animation.crossFade(background-image-1, background-image-2);
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work.  The only documentation or example I can find is the very vague MSDN docs, which simply say to supply the outgoing and incoming element (which I assume refers to a HTML element, rather than a CSS class).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You'd need two elements to cross fade. You can't cross fade a single element's background image.

Comment: Are you saying this effect is not possible, or simply that it's not possible like this?  (if the latter, then how?)

Comment: You can't cross fade with only one element. You need two elements (layered).